# Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04 Dual boot, grub menu not showing!

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I've installed Ubuntu 11.04 alongside with Windows 7. Everything is fine until i want to enter windows 7. When I start my PC, after normal boot, there is no Grub or OS Selection menu, and my system loads straight into Ubuntu.

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you install using Wubi (the Windows installer) or using a liveUSB or LiveDVD?

Comment: Try pressing `shift` while booting and see if the Grub menu loads.

Answer (score 4):

If you installed ubuntu without Wubi,
Run the following command in Ubuntu Terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This command will update your GRUB menu.If "Windows" seems in the output, you should set the timeout of GRUB menu.

Run this command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the value of GRUB_TIMEOUT in the file to 5 or whatever you want in order to show GRUB when booting.

then run this command again:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Or instead of this operations, press the Shift to open GRUB menu each time when booting.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the links below. They have helped me. Can help you as well. Choose the best that suits you. Cheers

Win7 installed first and Win7 still controlling startup after Linux installation ( http://thpc.info/dual/win7/dualboot_win7+ubuntu1210_bcd_on_win7.html )

or

Windows 7 installed first and Ubuntu's GRUB2 on Windows partition controlling startup http://thpc.info/dual/win7/dualboot_win7+ubuntu1210_grub_mbr_on_win7.html

www linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/comment-page-5/#comments